# Keeping track of all instances of a subclass in the superclass

Tags: java, oop

I have the following, stripped-down Java code:

```
// Class, in it's own file

import java.util.*;

public class Superclass {
    protected List<Subclass> instances = new ArrayList<>();

    public class Subclass extends Superclass {
        private int someField;

        public Subclass(int someValue) {
            this.someField = someValue;
            updateSuperclass();
        }

        private void updateSuperclass() {
            super.instances.add(this);
        }
    }
}

// Implementation, somewhere else, everything has been imported properly

Superclass big = new Superclass();
Subclass little1 = big.new Subclass(1);
Subclass little2 = big.new Subclass(2);
Subclass little3 = big.new Subclass(3);
```

I want to implement a method in `Superclass` to do something with all the `Subclass`es.  When a `Subclass` is created, it *should* add itself to a list in `Superclass`, but whenever I try to loop through that list in `Superclass`, it says the size is 1.  The first element in the list (`instances.get(0)`) just spits out a String with all the proper information, but not in object form, and not separately.  It's like every time I go to `add` to the list, it gets appended to the first (or zeroeth) element in String form.

How can I solve this so I can maintain an `ArrayList` of `Subclass`es to later loop over and run methods from?  I'm definitely a beginner at Java, which doesn't help my case.

Comment: Note that Subclass != Inner class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh man, now I'm even more confused.  I suppose a subclass would be something that inherits methods from a superclass, and an inner class is what I have?  I feel like I need the inner class, though, so I can use `super.instances.add`

Comment: Yes, a sub class is just a class that extends another. [An Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) is a class that is declared inside another class. You can combine the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is a count then I suggest a static value that is updated in the constructor of the parent class.

```
private static int instanceCount = 0;
public Constructor() {
    instanceCount++;
}
```

If you absolutely need every instance in a list so you can do something with them then I recommend you strongly re-consider your design.

You can always create a utility class that will let you maintain the list of objects to run processes on. It's more "Object Oriented" that way. You can also create one class that has all of the operations and then a simpler bean class that has only the data values.

But, if you insist, you can still use the same technique.

```
private static List<SuperClass> list = new LinkedList<SuperClass>;
public Constructor() {
    list.add(this)
}
```

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to seriously reconsider my design for this one.  For now - after putting the List as `static` - it seems to be working exactly as intended.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Each instance gets its own copy of your superclass's variables.

What you want to do is make the variable "static" by putting the static keyword before it. You probably don't even need the superclass accomplish what you're trying to do.